# Insert a dot before last character

Tags: c#, string-formatting

is it possible to get a string like "45.6" from an `int a = 456;` using string.Format?

Comment: check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math operations may yield different results in different cultures. You may get `,` instead of `.`. Try this

```
var aStr = a.ToString();
var res = aStr.Insert(aStr.Length - 1, ".")
```

Comment: yes, probably it is the best solution but thx to all, all answers are useful.

Answer (score 2):

Divide by 10 (as double).

You need to take the current culture into account, too. To always get a dot, use `InvariantCulture`.

To avoid floating point imprecision issues (something like 45 -> 4.49999999), make sure to only print the first digit by specifying "0.0" format.

```
int i = 123;
var s = String.Format (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.0}", i / 10.0);
```

Comment: To keep the precision, you can also divide by a decimal, not a float/double. I.e. print `i / 10m`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using IFormatProvider. (Can customize into any format)

```
int val = 456;  
string s = string.Format(new CustomerFormatter(),"{0:1d}", val);
string s1 = string.Format(new CustomerFormatter(), "{0:2d}", val);
Console.WriteLine(s); //45.6
Console.WriteLine(s1); //4.56

 public class CustomerFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (!this.Equals(formatProvider))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            string customerString = arg.ToString();
             switch (format)
            {
                case "1d":
                    return customerString.Insert(customerString.Length - 1, ".");
                case "2d":
                    return customerString.Insert(customerString.Length - 2, ".");

                default:
                    return customerString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int a = 456;
        String aString = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", a / 10, ".", a % 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Int32 a = 456;

String aString = a.ToString();
aString = aString.Insert((aString.Length - 1), ".")
```